# PHP exec returns null calling a deamon

Tags: php, linux, exec, bitcoin

I'm trying to make an crypto currency exchange for a project, it's made with php + electrum bitcoin wallet + electrum litecoin wallet.
The php script works perfectly running on bash (php /location/script.php) but it returns null on the browser.
I think it has something to do with the user running the command...

```
On bash --> linux_user
On browser --> www-data
```

I read it can be fixed running the command with sudo... It keeps working on bash, but still return null on the browser.

My command is :

```
exec("electrum version",$return);
```

the return variable is "2.5.4" on bash and null on browser.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post more codes on your PHP? or what is the output of `echo exec("electrum version");` ?

Comment: I'm not sure if posting more codes will help with the question... the output of the exec is 2.5.4 without the quotes.

Comment: Without the quotes? `exec(electrum version, $return);` ? Syntax error it is.